# database id's are interchanged android sqlite

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

Good Day everyone. I have this code and  i face problem in deleting. For example, my list of names are Junko, Gemina and Fukar. If i view each, they show same details. Now, if I delete any of them, ex. I delete Fukar, it will be deleted successfully but when I click on Gemina, the detail that appears is of Junko. If i click Junko, it says "*Unfortunately the app stopped working*". If I add new Name, ex. Nimrod, It will add successfully, but when i view Nimrod, the detail of Gemina will appear. And if i add another name, Vourin, the data of Gemina will appear its like their ids are interchanged and I think the error is in the delete part. I appreciate any comment. Thanks.

Below is my DBHelper.java

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;



public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactdb.sqlite";
public static final String CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME = "mycontacts";
public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_ID  = "id";
public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_STUNAME = "name";
public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_STUPHONE = "phone";
public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_STUSTREET = "street";
public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_STUEMAIL = "email";
public static final String CONTACTS_COLUMN_STUCITY = "place";

private HashMap hp;

public DBHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null, 3);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(
            "create table mycontacts " +
                    "(id integer primary key autoincrement, name text,phone text,email text, street text,place text)"
    );
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS mycontacts");
    onCreate(db);
}
public boolean addStudentContact(String contactname,String contactphone,String contactstreet,String contactemail, String contactplace){
    /*,*/
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contantValues = new ContentValues();
    contantValues.put("name",contactname);
    contantValues.put("phone", contactphone);
    contantValues.put("street",contactstreet);
    contantValues.put("email",contactemail);
    contantValues.put("place",contactplace);
    db.insert("mycontacts", null, contantValues);
    db.close();
    return true;
}
public boolean updateStudentContact(Integer contactid,String contactname,String contactphone,String contactstreet,String contactemail, String contactplace)
{
    /*,String contactname,*/
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contantValues = new ContentValues();
    contantValues.put("name",contactname);
    contantValues.put("phone", contactphone);
    contantValues.put("street",contactstreet);
    contantValues.put("email",contactemail);
    contantValues.put("place",contactplace);
    db.update("mycontacts", contantValues, "id = ?", new String[]{Integer.toString(contactid)});
    db.close();
    return true;
}
public Integer deleteContact(Integer id){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.delete("mycontacts","id = ?",new String[]{Integer.toString(id)});
}
public Cursor getData(int contactid){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor res=db.rawQuery("Select * from mycontacts where id = " + contactid + "", null);
    return res;
}
public int numberOfRows(){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    int numRows=(int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db,CONTACTS_TABLE_NAME);
    return numRows;
}
 public ArrayList<Person> getAllStudentContacts(){
    ArrayList<Person> arraylist= new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("Select * from mycontacts",null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            Person person = new Person();
            person.name =   cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_STUNAME));
            person.ID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_ID));
            arraylist.add(person);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return arraylist;
}
}
```

DisplayContact.java

```
package com.test.ppandey.contactapp;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DisplayContact extends AppCompatActivity {
int from_Where_I_Am_Coming = 0;
private DBHelper mydb;
TextView name;
TextView phone;
TextView email;
TextView street;
TextView place;
int id_To_Update = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_contact);

    name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    phone = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextPhone);
    email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextStreet);
    street = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    place = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editTextCity);

    mydb = new DBHelper(this);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    {
        int Value = extras.getInt("id");

        if (Value > 0) {
            //means this is the view part not the add contact part.
            Cursor rs = mydb.getData(Value);
            id_To_Update = Value;
            rs.moveToFirst();

            String stuname = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_STUNAME));
            String stuphone = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_STUPHONE));
            String stuemail = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_STUEMAIL));
            String stustreet = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_STUSTREET));
            String stuplace = rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.CONTACTS_COLUMN_STUCITY));

            if (!rs.isClosed()) {
                rs.close();
            }
            Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

            name.setText((CharSequence) stuname);
            name.setFocusable(false);
            name.setClickable(false);

            phone.setText((CharSequence) stuphone);
            phone.setFocusable(false);
            phone.setClickable(false);

            email.setText((CharSequence) stuemail);
            email.setFocusable(false);
            email.setClickable(false);

            street.setText((CharSequence) stustreet);
            street.setFocusable(false);
            street.setClickable(false);

            place.setText((CharSequence) stuplace);
            place.setFocusable(false);
            place.setClickable(false);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        int Value = extras.getInt("id");
        if (Value > 0) {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_display_contact, menu);
        } else {
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.Edit_Contact:
            Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            name.setEnabled(true);
            name.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            name.setClickable(true);

            phone.setEnabled(true);
            phone.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            phone.setClickable(true);

            email.setEnabled(true);
            email.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            email.setClickable(true);

            street.setEnabled(true);
            street.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            street.setClickable(true);

            place.setEnabled(true);
            place.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
            place.setClickable(true);

            return true;
        case R.id.Delete_Contact:

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage(R.string.deleteContact)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            mydb.deleteContact(id_To_Update);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // User cancelled the dialog
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog d = builder.create();
            d.setTitle("Are you sure ?");
            d.show();

            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}

public void saveData(View view) {
    /*, */
/*            mydb.addContact(name.getText().toString(),email.getText().toString(), street.getText().toString(), place.getText().toString(), phone.getText().toString());
    finish();*/
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        int Value = extras.getInt("id");
        if (Value > 0) {
            if (mydb.updateStudentContact(id_To_Update,   name.getText().toString(), phone.getText().toString(), street.getText().toString(),email.getText().toString(), place.getText().toString())) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record not updated", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            if (mydb.addStudentContact(name.getText().toString(), phone.getText().toString(),street.getText().toString(), email.getText().toString(),  place.getText().toString())) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Successfully Added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Record not added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
}
```

}

MainActivity.java

```
package com.test.ppandey.contactapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE="MESSAGE";
private ListView objListView;
DBHelper db;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    db=new DBHelper(this);
    ArrayList<Person> arrayList=db.getAllStudentContacts();
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);

    objListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    objListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    objListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            long id_to_search = id;
            Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
            dataBundle.putLong("id", id_to_search);
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DisplayContact.class);
            intent.putExtras(dataBundle);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
   /* int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);*/
    super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    switch(item.getItemId())
    {
        case R.id.item1:Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
            dataBundle.putInt("id", 0);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),DisplayContact.class);
            intent.putExtras(dataBundle);

            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    db=new DBHelper(this);
    ArrayList<Person> arrayList=db.getAllStudentContacts();
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter=new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arrayList);

    objListView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    objListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
}
```

}

activity_display_contact.xml

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
>

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="350dp"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.test.ppandey.contactapp.DisplayContact">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="82dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" >
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextStreet"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextStreet"
        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextName"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="@string/name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextCity"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="28dp"
        android:onClick="saveData"
        android:text="@string/save" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextEmail"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="@string/email"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextPhone"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="@string/phone"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/editTextEmail"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView5"
        android:text="@string/street"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextCity"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/editTextName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextEmail"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editTextCity"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editTextCity"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/editTextEmail"
        android:text="@string/country"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextStreet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextName"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextPhone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="text" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextPhone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/editTextStreet"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editTextName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="phone|text" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Person.java

```
package com.test.ppandey.contactapp;

/**
 * Created by Ariel on 08/03/2016.
 */
public class Person {

public String name;
public long ID;

private Person person; {
    name = new String(name);

 }
 private Person id; {
    ID = new long(id);

  }
}
```

I added Person.java and edited MainActivity.java and DBHelper.java

Comment: The IDs of your entries in the database do not change, if an entry is ID 2, it will always be ID 2, even if ID 1 is deleted. Are you keeping a list of IDs and substracting 1 when you delete an entry?

Comment: not really sure mate, i was following a tutorial for this one, and i'm still googling for a solution for this one

Comment: Please post the code where you access the entries.

Comment: You posted the code where you delete the contact. I'd like to see the code where you start the Details Activity, as that's where the problem will be - you pass an ID as an extra to the intent, and that ID must be incorrect at the source.

Comment: `int id_to_search = position + 1;` nope. the position in your array is not related to the id in the database. especially if you delete items.

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

```
int id_to_search = position + 1;
```

You are assuming that the IDs and the positions are in sync. This is only true as long as you do not remove any entries. Instead of using the position to reference an entry, you have to use the ID, as that's immutable.

When you pull the entries from your database, you need to pull the name and the ID, and keep that data in your adapter, so you can reference an entry by its ID.

Some code below (just a skeleton):

1) Create a model for your data

```
public class Person {
    // consider making private and adding accessors
    public String name;
    public long id;
}
```

2) when you pull your data, pull the name and the ID (you may expand the Person class and this function to pull additional data):

```
public List<Person> getAllStudentContacts(){
    List<Person> arraylist= new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor=db.rawQuery("Select * from mycontacts",null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            Person person = new Person();
            person.name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_STUNAME));
            person.id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumIndex(CONTACTS_COLUMN_ID));
            arraylist.add(prson);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return arraylist;
}
```

Then in your adapter you use the ID in the Person object to reference it, instead of the position.

Comment: forgive the request mate but maybe I could get bits of codes for this? I've been trying to edit but not really good at this android

Answer (score -1):

Are you refreshing your "List of Names" from your android App afer every insert/delete?

Maybe by calling getAllStudentContacts() from your code after every insert/delete to refill your List of names of your android app?

Good Luck